# Is there any way to test the ability to access websites on different network connections without turning network connections on and off?

Tags: wi-fi, browser, mobile-data, internet

Is there any way to test the ability to access websites on different network connections without turning network connections on and off?

For example.. Suppose you have a smartphone with 2 mobile sim cards and one WiFi.  So, three network connections.

Accessing a website in chrome doesn't work.

I want to know for each network connection, whether it can access a website.

I don't want to turn off any network connections in my diagnosis to find out.

I want to be able to diagnose by specifying particular network connections to try for accessing a website.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You should specify if the device is rooted or not.

Comment: @MorrisonChang It's an OPPO A9  not rooted, i'm not sure how one would root it. If it is possible to root it then I might. I'd be interested for a solution on phones that are rooted and on phones that are not. I think both would be useful to people